# Is PDO MySQL needed for only one row?

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

Do I need to use PDO on queries, without user input, that just outputs one row? I'm thinking that I should use it without PDO for a little performance increase.

Comment: I’m racking my brain to try and decipher your question. What’s your concern? PDO is a way of connecting to a database and running queries. It can be used to query a database for one row or many rows. Could you explain your use case a bit more, and I may be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: How is the number of returned rows relevant? Is it because PDO is too complicated? What would you think is any simpler?

Answer (score 2):

It would be a good idea to use PDO, even for such queries. I believe the mysql_ functions (part of the API) are in the process of being deprecated, if they have not been deprecated already.

Comment: really?! mysql functions are being deprecated? O_O

Comment: The mysql_ library is. PDO & MySQLi are recommended over it

Comment: i can understand though, PDO does make switching dbs a breeze

Comment: @webdev: What rock have you been under :) This has been the case for a loongg time. MySQLi exists for at least half a decade.

Comment: that rock was client side dev, html css js ;)